# Windows 10 Desktop App Docking. How to Disable?

Tags: windows-10, desktop, docking

See Picture.
[image: Auto Docking Bar]

Windows 10.
How do I disable this annoying auto docking Bar that comes up when I'm moving Apps on Desktop?
Is this built into Windows 10?
If not, maybe it's software that came bundled on the Laptop? But I can't find it.
Laptop is a MSI GE72VR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not a built-in feature in Windows 10.

In order to find out this docking bar, clean boot computer and run your usual apps, when it appears, open task manager and check which third-party programs are running, close them one by one until docking bar disappears, then you can confirm which one generates this bar.

In addition, Microsoft tool named Process Explorer can also help you.

Comment: Thank you. Just knowing that it wasn't built in feature of Windows 10 helped me solve.  It was a program called MSI True Color that came with Laptop. It has a feature called Desktop Partition that I was able to disable.

Comment: ok, thanks for updating, your experience will help other other users